# How to avoid adding same item to CoreData using swift?

Tags: swift, core-data

The user will be able to add an item to the cart, so when he adds one item I want him to not be able to add it again to avoid any duplication. Here is the code where I send the data to coredata after user add an item to cart.

```
 @IBAction func btnBuy(_ sender: UIButton) {
         let context = objAppDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
         let tblCart = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Cart", into: context)
                 do {
                     tblCart.setValue(lblProductName.text!, forKey: "name")
                     tblCart.setValue(Int(lblQty.text!), forKey: "quantity")
                     tblCart.setValue(id, forKey: "id")
                     tblCart.setValue(uid, forKey: "uid")
                     // there is more

                     try context.save()
                     print("data Saved")
                     
                     
                 } catch{
                     print("error in database")
                 }
   
    }
```

I fetched two items data of same product see how it's look

```
(lldb) po data
<Cart: 0x6000025cdc70> (entity: Cart; id: 0x8ebb1a1397c1bf8e <x-coredata://E72A6C76-3400-44A8-9FA6-61AA874CEF9B/Cart/p2>; data: {
    category = Metalwork;
    id = "-MEbK8UfDQdweqaUc2Cb";
    itemType = Product;
    name = "Omani Dagger";
    price = 320;
    quantity = 4;
    sellerID = "-M9Dp5GFFTt9bdqtpjrw";
    stoke = 1;
    totalPrice = 0;
    uid = ZwTXwUWPmzfY6Pgc1S2gpMZu9x72;
})

(lldb) po data
<Cart: 0x6000025cdc20> (entity: Cart; id: 0x8ebb1a1397c5bf8e <x-coredata://E72A6C76-3400-44A8-9FA6-61AA874CEF9B/Cart/p3>; data: {
    category = Metalwork;
    id = "-MEbK8UfDQdweqaUc2Cb";
    itemType = Product;
    name = "Omani Dagger";
    price = 320;
    quantity = 4;
    sellerID = "-M9Dp5GFFTt9bdqtpjrw";
    stoke = 1;
    totalPrice = 0;
    uid = ZwTXwUWPmzfY6Pgc1S2gpMZu9x72;
})
```

**Now how I will avoid the duplication of same product**

Comment: The normal solution for this is to execute a fetch request first and if successful then update the fetched object else create a new one but since your 2 objects are exactly the same it looks to me that you have some other issue since you are saving the exact same data twice.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson could you please explain how to update the fetched object cause I tried many solution and I wasn't able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you are tapping your *buy* button you are creating a new `Cart` instance with `NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName:into:)`.

In order to eliminate your *duplicate* carts, you first need to determine if a `Cart` already exists. You can use a `NSFetchRequest` on the `NSManagedObjectContext` to retrieve the existing cart.

```swift
let fetch = Cart.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Cart>
fetch.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(Cart.id), "EXISTING ID TO LOCATE")
if let cart = try context.fetch(fetch).first {
    // update cart
} else {
    // create cart
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add unique constraints to the models (Constraints table)

[image]

Then you can change merge policy, defining how CoreData should handle conflicts

```
  self.container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
```